# Using vuejs with userfrosting framework

Tags: php, vue.js, userfrosting

I'm using vuejs to create a complex website that will have user registration and login. I want to implement userfrosting framweork to manage users registration/login workflow but I'm not sure how to implement in in my existing vue project. I've read the documentation and I've successfully installed all the needed dependencies and I'm able to see the final directory. The problem is that it will rely on a custom `index.php` file and I already have my vue template to use. At the moment I've created the userfrosting folder inside the src folder of my vue project. How I can make the two things working togheter?

Comment: UserFrosting is intended to be the base framework you build upon. It's not really possible to "include" UF inside an existing framework. And even so, if you use it as a base framework for your API, UF is not (yet) made to be used with VueJS. At the minimum, you would need to recreate the whole UF UI in vue.

Comment: is there a better alternative to it?

Comment: Laravel Jetstream might be the closest I know of